# Fourier Transform of Entropic Utility Function

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying find the Fourier transform $F(u)$ for the utility function for the entropic risk measure, which is given below. However my knowledge on Fourier analysis is fairly poor.

$f(x)=\dfrac{e^{\gamma x}-1}{\gamma} $

I'm running into problems because when I try to do the integration I end up evaluating $\dfrac{e^{x(\gamma +iu)}}{\gamma (\gamma +iu)}-\dfrac{e^{iux}}{iu\gamma}$ at infinity. Could anyone shed some light on what I'm messing up?

Comment: How do you compute the Fourier transform of $f$ when $f \notin L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$? Note that if $\gamma > 0$ then $f$ blows up at $+\infty$ and if $\gamma < 0$ then $f$ blows up at $-\infty$. Could you show us your working?

Comment: $e^{\gamma x}$ does not have a Fourier Transform even in a distributional sense.  $e^{-|\gamma x|}$ does have a Fourier Transform.